# Visio 2016 - How to ungroup a shape which contains multiple geometries

Tags: geometry, visio

Yeah.  Like how Magnum p.i. says it...),

I have downloaded someone else's vsd file with a real big object on it.

I have ungrouped it,  but all I got were a bunch of shapes,  each of which appears to contain multiple geometries.

The one that I am looking at right now contains 33 geometries.  The ungroup button is dimmed.  Pressing ctrl + shift + U does not do anything further.

How do I break them down to where each geometry winds up being its own shape?

Why doesn't Stack Overflow let me start out the possting by saying, "Hi Guys,"?

Comment: What you mean 33 geometries: group shape with 33 sub-shapes into or single merged shape with 33 Geometry sections in it ShapeSheet? Please read [Groups versus Merged Shapes](https://flylib.com/books/en/2.268.1.35/1/)

Comment: Let me see if I can describe it a differently.

I ungrouped a real big shape.  The smaller shapes still appear to be larger groups.

The ungroup button or commands are dimmed out and do not work on breaking these shapes down further.

Opening up the ShapeSheet on one of these shapes,  which appears to be a group,  reveals that it contains 33 geometries.   The ShapeSheets on some of these other shapes are similar,  looking like a very big object with multiple shapes in it,  but it is really one shape with multiple geometries in it.

I know that part of the problem is that I am a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Sad but truth...
No way, we cant ungroup merged shape!
[image: Visio. Merged shapes]

Yes, you can delete some sections.
[image: Delete ShapeSheet section]

Comment: What is a merged shape?
Is there some way of working with merged shapes?
Could the individual geometries be deleted?

Comment: Yes, you can delete some geometries